# How to attach existing EC2 instances to auto scaling group in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I created 2 EC2 instances using terraform.
Is there any way to attach them into auto scaling group using terraform?
I didn't find anything about this in the docs :/

I don't want to create them within the ASG, only attached them.
As I said the instances were generated by terraform script as well as everything else (ASG, SG...).

Thank you

Comment: Both ASG and the instance are created as part of same terraform script?

Comment: Can you edit your question to share what you've done so far? Have you created both the ASG and the instances with Terraform? Or is this a one off attachment as you migrate things? Is there a reason not to create the instances directly in the ASG and remove the old instances?

Comment: I wrote the instances were created by terraform

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this is not possible via Terraform directly

However you could run the [attach-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/attach-instances.html) AWS cli command.

If this needed to be performed in terraform you could put the command into a [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) resource.